# Reverse image search/duplicate finder like Google but locally?

Tags: windows, file-management, search

I am not looking to find all duplicate files.

I have an image that is low resolution on my desktop, sadly as it's low resolution it's not really usable.

But somewhere on my computer, on one of  the 4 hard drives, I have that exact same image but high resolution and higher quality but I can not find it.

It would be helpful to be able to do reverse image search locally, offline.

I am looking for a tool that will resolve my struggles.
Ideally for Windows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/311633/free-visual-similarity-image-for-a-local-hard-drive-search Some good suggestions in this question

Answer (score 0):

This looks worth a try.  (Whatever happened to Picasa?)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/imgseek/

LATER:
OK, I've tried it.  Not worth the trouble.   The search continues...

But I'll leave this answer up.  It's useful to know what NOT to try!

Comment: The windows executable is 18 years old. Plus I see good amount of problems/bugs. Did not try it, but IMHO this software is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Gemini is good - https://macpaw.com/gemini
…but Mac only & pretty expensive for a one-trick pony £40 UKP.

I does handle more than just pictures, though. It can find many types of file & folder dupes & does a pretty good job of figuring out which should be considered the 'original' & which are just copies or reductions/low quality.

[image]

<sup>Included here just for completenss/future googlers.</sup>

Comment: Let's hope the original/copy is applicable only for images. It's hard for me to realize what can be original/copy (with low quality/reduced) ZIP :D